# Likelihood notation - Bayesian models

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, notation

I was reading up about variational Bayesian logistic regression here: https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlpr/2015/log/15b_lr_and_svi.pdf

And the author first defines the model likelihood as

$$ p(y|x,w) $$

But then in applying bayes rule, he redefines it as

$$ p(D|w)$$

Why is that allowed? Is it because Bayesians view data as given/fixed?

And how does the notation work more generally?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common notation. D is considered a training set (see "Gaussian Processes" by Rasmussen, http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf, p.8 for reference) which "connects" a certain x with a certain y, hence there holds

$D = \{{(x_i,y_i) | i=1,...,n}\}$.

So yes, in my opinion you could say that this holds because data is being "fixed" once observing it or at least nailed down to a certain mean and variance.

Comment: Do you have a paper or reference for this since the link doesn’t explicitly state this

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$P(y|x, w)$ is not the model likelihood. it is a point wise prediction. In logistic regression it is the sigmoid over the logits $wx +b$.

if $p_i = P(y_i|x_i, w)$

Then the likelihood of this single point is:

$p_i^{y_i} * (1-p_i)^{1-y_i}$

$P(D|w)$ is a notation for the model likelihood for the entire dataset. In the logistic regression setup we usually use log loss or cross entropy which is the negative log likelihood, which is basically the sum of the log likelihood of each point (i.e. sum over $log(p_i^{y_i} * (1-p_i)^{1-y_i})$)

Comment: Yeah you’re right, but the author never seems to actually use the Bernoulli likelihood, instead opting to leave it in the link form and calling it the model likelihood. Any guesses as to why?

Comment: Where do you see it in the document?

Comment: Usually logistic regression is given as $$p(y_i | x_i) = \text{bern}(\sigma(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x_i))$$. So it just seems weird that they're using $p_i=p(y_i=1 | ~.~)$ as the likelihood.